# i want to send some notifications to observers when some event occurs. and i also want to know how observer catch/handle/receive that notification?

Tags: iphone

while reading cocoa fundamental guide i have gone through:

- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver selector:(SEL)notificationSelector name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender

I am getting all theories, but actually i am looking for a real example where it is used ?

Can any one give some sample example.

Actually i want to send some notifications to observers when some event occurs.

and i also want to know how observer catch/handle/receive that notification ??

Thanks

Comment: I once observed the contentOffset of a UIScrollView, so I could cause other views to follow the movement of the scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen for notifications, add code similar to this in the instance that you want to receive notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doThisWhenNotificationRecd:)
                                             name:@"SOME_NOTIFICATION_NAME" 
                                           object:nil];
```

When you want to post a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:@"SOME_NOTIFICATION_NAME" object:nil]];
```

I use code similar to this to update my UI while processing an in app purchase.

Comment: And if you were asking about how Key Value Observing is implemented under the hood, it is done through a technique called "isa swizzling".  Whenever a message is sent to an object, the selector is passed to the class pointed at by the object's `isa` pointer.  When you add a KVO to an object, the Obj-C runtime subclasses the object's class, creating a subclass that fires a notification when stuff is changed.  It then reroutes the `isa` pointer to point to the custom subclass, yet keeps the `class` pointer deceitfully pointing to the object's nominal class.