# How to make custom notification so that whenever event occurs it will handle in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Hi I want to make custom local notification so that whenever popover is visible it will handle by that notification.
so that as multiple time the popover is visible it will handle by that notification 
Currently i have partially done this but problem is that if i want to run notification's selector method multiple times i have to post that notification wherever i want. 
used this link to implement it 
[i want to send some notifications to observers when some event occurs. and i also want to know how observer catch/handle/receive that notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786942/i-want-to-send-some-notifications-to-observers-when-some-event-occurs-and-i-als)

Can i make notification like, once i postNotification in viewDidLoad it will handle as many times that event occurs?

Note-See the answer posted by me

Comment: Can i make notification like, once i postNotification in viewDidLoad it will handle as many times that event occurs?   indeed it happens in this way.

Comment: @AKV but when i post notification in viewDidLoad it is calling notification's selector method only at once

Answer (score 2):

Use this 
line before presenting popover

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dissmissPop:) name:@"popOver"  object:popOver.contentViewController];//popOver is your name of popover

-(void)dissmissPop:(id)sender{

   //method to be called
}
```

To call notification from popover use this

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"popOver" object:self];
```

Comment: This is good option but in 20 files where i present popover & dismiss popover i have to do like this ...that i dont't want to do

Comment: are you calling 20 popover from the same class? For dismiss u just need to add one line.

Comment: you can write a singleton class for the popover. You'll then just have to add observer in all the 20 files, and post it on your event.

Comment: @Dhara no in differnt files

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dissmissPop:) name:@"popOver"  object:popOver.contentViewController]; in this line we are passing an object popOver so it will be just valid for that only. Use can reuse a popver

Comment: @piya, Dhara, Nikita [all Bhariya names :) ]  Notification can be used 1 to many, many to many, so I am confused what is your exact problem... no need to make a singleton class just for handling.

Comment: @AKV but when i post notification in viewDidLoad it is calling notification's selector method only at once

Comment: @piya when you post notification, then the notification selector will be called only once. It will called as many times as you post notification until and unless you remove the notification observer.

Comment: @piya: your requirement is that "When popup is displayed, call an action". Correct?

Comment: @AKV yes ,when popover visible set user interaction disabled & when popover is not visible set user interaction enabled

Comment: what about making a controller for popover, it will check if it is in active state, didLoad etc call a selector:

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are  same as broadcast receivers. If we  register as broadcast receiver whenever new email arrives. But do you actually post the event notification? No. Someone else does. Similarly when keyboard is shown the notification is posted by the system. Send you only get notified.

The system posts whenever the keyboard is gonna appear. This should make it clear that if you want to post custom notifications you have to post it every time there's need for it to.

So if you make custom notification you have to postNotification when ever you want to post it.